# how to Cloth Simulation in html5 canvas + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

i have found the source of an cloth simulation. Here is 
[JSFIDDLE.NET](http://jsfiddle.net/tahmid/cUaE6/)

```
<canvas id="c" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            xyz();
        });
        function xyz() 
        {
             a = "d#ocumt;c#.getElemtById('c'Ub=c.getContext('2d'Uf=10;c.wid=g=c.height=j=500;k=[Ml=[Mq=hH;r=o=1;D_5V<fV++,y_8Qz=[MDiH,_5J<fJ++,x_8Qz]={x:x,y:y:1,k:x,j:y}h>0Qpush([h,h])}(i>0?push([h,h]):0)@k[0][0]S=k[0][9]SH;nAclearRect(0,0,g,jUKffp=z]pwi(pQnx*1~-k*~;ny*1~-j*~+(_0125*rUk=x;j=y;nx;ny@@K2lga=lMs01t23dtW-sW`tZ-sZ`e#x+dy`i=(de-_064)/((de+_064)*(sS+tS))ssW+#i;sZ+#i}i&ttWNi;tZNi@}Olga=lMbeginPa(Us01t23!To(sW*g,sZ*jUlineTo(tW*g,tZ*jUstro()@;setInterval(n,35UFdownAw=f;Kffp=zMdxLX/g-pW`yLY/j-pZ;nw#x+dynw<wQw=nw=p@}F!AqW=q.kLX/gZ=q.jLY/jSH};FupAF!=nullS=o};}`.onydownAi&e.yCode==71Qr=(r=H)?1:0}oH}`.onyupAo=1}";
            for (b in c = "VGO;qkeyNxN]MJG-1l.J&x=+=y=en!moveS!HQb.,i[ithKDhHV<]]K=kK~.99`;d@}}&f(#=d_.0zk[h]Z.yW.xV;hU);S.iQ){ODiHJ<N*dM];L=e.pageK[a[J;iH=0G++){Fd.onmouseDfor(A=function(e){".split(""))
                a = a.replace(RegExp(c[b][0], "g"), c[b].slice(1));
            eval(a)
        }
```

but code looks alien to me. i want to fill the rect with my image how to do it? 
how to fill those box with image or any tutorial on this type of cloth simulation. give me some direction

Comment: Here's the [actual code](http://jsfiddle.net/cUaE6/1/).

Comment: and a slightly [better version](http://jsfiddle.net/cUaE6/2/) with refactoring some variable names.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks for the links .slightly better version is not giving output.

Comment: I must have made a mistake, well c is the canvas element and b is the 2d context, which is mostly all you need to know to read it with moderate difficulty.

Comment: no problem @FakeRainBrigand i found the mistake. by the way do u have documentation about this code ? i really need to understand this.

Comment: There's some more elaborate code [here](http://andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/cloth/).  Just view source to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a physical cloth simulation with some controls, draws only edges of cloth mesh. You need a triangle drawer, so you can assign coordinates of your image into this mesh. You can use WebGL which does this job cool or to code triangle drawer on 2d context by yourself. Take a look at this [demo](http://gyu.que.jp/jscloth/) I found few years ago which demonstrate 3d cloth simulation on 2d context. Also, check a code which draws triangles (it's [here](http://gyu.que.jp/jscloth/parpevision.js)), so you can use it on your own. Good luck!